# create a better query that sums two tables

Tags: mysql

I created a query, that collects data from two tables, summs them up and shows the count of the cases and the total summ:

```
SELECT
    count(ut.id) AS total
    , ( SUM(internal_account) - SUM(( SELECT
            SUM( ub.bill_summs )
        FROM
            u_billing ub
        WHERE
            ub.bill_types = 'correction'
            AND ub.contract_id = ut.contract_id
      )) ) AS summ
FROM  
    u_transactions ut
WHERE
    ut.nulled = 0
    AND ut.type = 'comission'
    AND ut._status = 'not_paid'
    AND DATE( ut.add_timestamp ) = DATE( '2012-05-11' );
```

but it is really slow. On test cases it gave this result:

```
+-------+-------+
| total | summ  |
+-------+-------+
|   182 | 15105 |
+-------+-------+
1 row in set (4.13 sec)
```

It is 4.13 seconds on 182 cases and for only 1 day, but my live server has over 600k cases, so this will be **extremely** slow.

Any ideas, how I can rewrite the query for better performance?

---

Solution with remade query(ies):

```
DELETE FROM tmpContractSums;
INSERT INTO tmpContractSums
SELECT
    ub.contract_id
    , SUM( ub.bill_summs ) AS bill_summs
FROM
    u_billing ub
WHERE
    ub.bill_types = 'correction'
GROUP BY ub.contract_id;

SELECT
    count(ut.id) AS total
    , ( SUM(internal_account) - SUM(bill_summs) )
FROM  
    u_transactions ut
LEFT JOIN tmpContractSums t ON ut.contract_id = t.contract_id
WHERE
    ut.nulled = 0
    AND ut.type = 'comission'
    AND ut._status = 'not_paid'
    AND ut.add_timestamp BETWEEN '2012-05-11 00:00:00' AND '2012-05-11 23:59:59';
```

Execution time: **500ms**

PS: Since I can't drop tables with webuser I just created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE tmpContractSums AS SELECT contract_id, bill_summs FROM u_billing WHERE 1 = 0;
```

and the I'm deleting the records. Not as fast as drop, but still way faster then original.

Comment: Did you run a query analyzer on it ?   And can you give us a description of `u_transactions` and `u_billing`m for instance does billing have a add_timestamp field or any other fields that join billing and transactions? ... also do you have any indexes?

Comment: Is it not possible for you to join u_billing ub and  u_transactions ut tables?

Comment: @Nix The only parameter, that allows to merge them is `contract_id`. And yes, I tried indexing, but nothing improves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply using a "temporary" table?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpContractSums;
CREATE TABLE tmpContractSums AS SELECT contract_id, bill_summs FROM u_billing WHERE 1 = 0;
INSERT INTO tmpContractSums
SELECT
    ub.contract_id
    SUM( ub.bill_summs ) AS bill_summs
FROM
    u_billing ub
WHERE
    ub.bill_types = 'correction'
GROUP BY ub.contract_id;

SELECT
    count(ut.id) AS total
    , ( SUM(internal_account) - COALESCE(bill_summs, 0) )
FROM  
    u_transactions ut
LEFT JOIN tmpContractSums t ON ut.contract_id = t.contract_id
WHERE
    ut.nulled = 0
    AND ut.type = 'comission'
    AND ut._status = 'not_paid'
    AND ut.add_timestamp BETWEEN '2012-05-11' AND '2012-05-11 23:59:59';
```

This should be faster and if you want you can add indexes to the "temporary table" or make it a table with engine=memory if you have enough space.

Or:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpContractSums;
CREATE TABLE tmpContractSums AS SELECT contract_id, bill_summs FROM u_billing WHERE 1 = 0;
INSERT INTO tmpContractSums
SELECT
    ub.contract_id
    SUM( ub.bill_summs ) AS bill_summs
FROM
    u_billing ub
WHERE
    ub.bill_types = 'correction'
GROUP BY ub.contract_id;

SELECT
    count(ut.id) AS total
    , ( SUM(internal_account) - (SELECT bill_summs FROM tmpContractSums t WHERE ut.contract_id = t.contract_id ) )
FROM  
    u_transactions ut
WHERE
    ut.nulled = 0
    AND ut.type = 'comission'
    AND ut._status = 'not_paid'
    AND ut.add_timestamp BETWEEN '2012-05-11' AND '2012-05-11 23:59:59';
```

Comment: I don't really understand this solution. Can you explain more how this works? Meaning I don't see where the table `tmpContractSums` is created...

Comment: It's automatically created by the `INSERT INTO`

Comment: Then why do I get this message? `MySQL Database Error: Table 'tmpcontractsums' doesn't exist`

Comment: @DainisAbols Sorry, corrected it. Sometimes I get confused by the many RDBMSs. In others the table gets automatically created.

Comment: Thank you, got it working in 500ms time. I posted the end result in question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
    SELECT 
        COUNT(A.id) AS total,
        (SUM(A.internal_account) - SUM(COALESCE(B.bill_sums, 0)) AS 'Sum'
    FROM
    u_transactions A
    LEFT JOIN u_billing B on A.contract_id = B.contract_id
    WHERE 
    A.nulled = 0 AND
    A.type = 'comission' AND
    A._status = 'not_paid' AND
    DATE(A.add_timestamp) = DATE('2012-05-11')
    AND B.bill_types = 'correction';
```

EDIT:

I didn't notice that you sum the results of the subquery.:

```
SELECT
    count(ut.id) AS total
    , ( SUM(internal_account) - **SUM**(( SELECT
            **SUM**( ub.bill_summs )
        FROM
            u_billing ub
        WHERE
            ub.bill_types = 'correction'
            AND ub.contract_id = ut.contract_id
      )) ) AS summ
FROM  
    u_transactions ut
```

maybe you can replace the sum with coalesce:

```
-COALESCE(( SELECT
        **SUM**( ub.bill_summs )
    FROM
        u_billing ub
    WHERE
        ub.bill_types = 'correction'
        AND ub.contract_id = ut.contract_id
  ),0)
```

Comment: This takes the same amount of time and gives wrong results at the end ;) Not all contracts in u_transactions have 'correction' data. Only some have.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it? I mean it must work much better.

```
SELECT
    count(ut.id) AS total
    , SUM(internal_account - COALESCE(ub.b_summs, 0)) summ
FROM u_transactions ut
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
                contract_id,
                SUM(bill_summs) b_summs
            FROM u_billing
            WHERE bill_types = 'correction'
            GROUP BY contract_id
        ) AS ub
        ON ub.contract_id = ut.contract_id
WHERE
    ut.nulled = 0
    AND ut.type = 'comission'
    AND ut._status = 'not_paid'
    AND DATE( ut.add_timestamp ) = DATE( '2012-05-11' );
```

Also, you must avoid using function on WHERE clause applied to table column. If you have index, using function not allow index using. Use this instead:

```
AND ut.add_timestamp >= DATE( '2012-05-11' ) AND ut.add_timestamp < DATE( '2012-05-12' );
```

Comment: `1 row in set (10.29 sec)` even slower :(

Comment: @DainisAbols OK. Do you try my last suggestion about add_timestamp ? Have you indexes in your table?

Comment: Just a minute, I'm testing :)

Comment: Sorry took so long, I added a few more indexes ( took 40 minutes to get it done ), but nothing changed. My query executes in `4s`, yours `10s` :(

Comment: @DainisAbols What about my last suggestion and can you show result of `SHOW INDEX IN {tblname}`?

Comment: I tried both options, but nothing helped. [tombob](http://stackoverflow.com/users/447489/tombom) suggestion works really nice.

Comment: [Here](http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/7107/1f4fb4b82c2c46218bd7a2b.png) are the indexes also.

Answer (score 0):

This should speed things up:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(ua.id) as total,
   SUM(ua.internal_account - ua.corrections) as 'sum'
FROM (  
    SELECT 
       ut.id,
       ut.internal_account,
       SUM(COALESCE(ub.bill_sums, 0)) AS corrections
    FROM
       u_transactions ut
          LEFT JOIN u_billing ub on ut.contract_id = ub.contract_id
    WHERE 
       ut.nulled = 0 AND
       ut.type = 'comission' AND
       ut._status = 'not_paid' AND
       DATE(ub.add_timestamp) = DATE('2012-05-11') AND 
       ut.bill_types = 'correction'
    GROUP BY
       ut.id
    ) as ua
```

Edit: corrected `add_timestamp` table prefix and inserted missing `GROUP BY`

Comment: Finally go to test it, it returns wrong results, but executes 1s faster ;)

Comment: @DainisAbols I put the wrong prefix on `add_timestamp`. Does it give correct results now?

Comment: @DainisAbols Durrr, forgot to put in the `GROUP BY`.  It'll be accurate now. maybe not as fast as tombom's answer though.